# Directive not being used

Tags: angular

I have the following directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewChecked, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[myMatchHeight]'})
export class MatchHeightDirective {

    // class name to match height
    @Input()
    myMatchHeight: any;

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
        console.log("were inside the directive");
    }
}
```

In my template I use it here

```
<div class="row" myMatchHeight="card">
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="card">  
  </div>
</div>
```

and I imported it into my app module and added it to my declarations, but nothing is logged to the console. Why?

Import

```
import {MatchHeightDirective} from './match-height.directive';
```

Declarations

```
declarations: [
AppComponent,
FullLayoutComponent,
SimpleLayoutComponent,
NAV_DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES,
BreadcrumbsComponent,
MatchHeightDirective,
SIDEBAR_TOGGLE_DIRECTIVES,
AsideToggleDirective,
```

],

Comment: Hi, can you add the app.module.ts blocks where you import the directive and add it to the declarations?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ttpsn5?file=app%2Fmatch-height.directive.ts. Post a complete minimal example, as I just did, reproducing the problem.